# Prove The Uniqueness Of Limits

Tags: calculus

If $$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L$$ and $$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L_0$$, then $$L=L_0$$.
Now as $$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L\tag{1}$$
Also $$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L_0\tag2$$
Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get
$$2\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L+L_0$$
$$\implies\lim_{x \to c}2f(x)=L+L_0$$
$$\implies 2L=L+L_0$$ $$(\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L)$$
$$\implies L=L_0$$
Am I Correct?

Comment: No, you are assuming $L=L_0$ using these steps.

Comment: In the first place, if a limit wasn't unique, you couldn't write $\lim=L$ at all (otherwise that would lead to the contradiction $L_0\ne L1\land L_0=L_1$.

Answer (score 2):

No you have used the uniqueness of limit to prove the uniqueness of limit.

You have added the two $\lim f(x)$ and assumed that the result is $2\lim f(x)$

How did you get $2\lim f(x)$ if you have two different limits?

Comment: Then what is the real proof

Comment: If there are two different limits $L$ and $L'$ then for $\epsilon = |L -L'|/2$ use definition of limit to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is wrong. It's not really your fault: The result is usually stated the way you stated it, but it shouldn't be! The notation $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ itself makes no sense unless we've already shown that limits are unique. If we're given that $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L_0$, and *if* the notation makes sense then we can simply say $$L=\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L_0.$$

A better way to state the result,  without implicitly assuming it's true, is

> > If $f(x)\to L$ as $x\to c$ and $f(x)\to L_0$ as $x\to c$ then $L_0=L$.

A similar problem with the notation: People often write "$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)\ne L$" as though it were the negation of "$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$". But "$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)\ne L$"  implies that there *is* such a thing as $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$, which does not follow from assuming that $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$ is false. The negation should be written $f(x)\not\to L$.

Comment: Notation $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ does make sense, because we can think about it as a set.

Comment: _If_ we think of it as a set, yes. But it's _not_ a set in the standard definition, it's a number.

Comment: It might be if we are concerned with general topology and not real analysis (i. e. Moore-Smith sequences).

Comment: Yes, if we change the question then the answer's different. _This_ question is about calculus.

Comment: I had to look  up "Moore-Smith sequences". Evidently they're just nets. For our purposes here there's no difference between nets and sequences - the proof of uniqueness is the  same, and then $\lim$ notation already assumes this uniqueness, exactly as for sequences.

Comment: Depends on how you understand calculus as a concept. I consider topology a part of calculus. I'd say it's more correct to say that we are talking about real analysis here.

Comment: So we're talking about real analysis - so what? That doesn't affect anything I said about the problems with the notation.

Comment: @Jakobian - the purpose of answering questions is to provide useful information to the questioner. It is not to confuse them by bringing up all sorts of ideas and topics that they are clearly not ready for.

Answer (score 1):

Option, a bit more formal:

Let $\epsilon/2 >0$ be given.

1) There is a a $\delta_1 >0$ s.t.

$|x-c| \lt \delta_1$ implies $|f(x)-L_1| \lt \epsilon/2$.

2) There is a $\delta_2 >0$ s.t.

$|x-c| \lt \delta_2$ implies $|f(x)-L_2| \lt \epsilon/2$.

With $\delta=\min (\delta_1,\delta_2)$ and

$|x-c| \lt \delta $:

$|L_1-L_2| =$

$|L_1-f(x)+f(x)-L_2| \le$

$|f(x)-L_1|+|f(x)-L_2| \lt$

$\epsilon/2 +\epsilon/2 =\epsilon$.

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary it follows $L_1=L_2$.